# Get JSON data from APEX class using php

Tags: php, salesforce, apex

So I have this APEX class that is triggered every time I create a contact in salesforce. The class then sends the data for the created contact to webservice that I've set. Here is the class

```
    @isTest
public class testWebhookTriggerTest {

    static SObject mock(String sobjectName) {
        SObjectType t = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectName);

        SObject o = t.newSobject();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> m = t.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        for (String fieldName : m.keySet()) {
            DescribeFieldResult f = m.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
            if (!f.isNillable() && f.isCreateable() && !f.isDefaultedOnCreate()) {
                if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Boolean) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), false);
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Currency) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 0);
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Date) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), Date.today());
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.DateTime) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), System.now());
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Double) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 0.0);
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Email) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 'foo@foo.com');
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Integer) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 0);
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Percent) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 0);
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Phone) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), '555-555-1212');
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.String) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 'TEST');
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.TextArea) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 'TEST');
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Time) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), System.now().time());
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.URL) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), 'http://example.com');
                }
                else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.PickList) {
                    o.put(f.getName(), f.getPicklistValues()[0].getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return o;
    }

    @isTest static void testTrigger() {
        SObject o = mock('Contact');

        Test.startTest();
        insert o;
        update o;
        delete o;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(200, Webhook.response.getStatusCode());
        System.assertEquals('https://alpahs.com/software/whatconverts/1/salesforceWebhook.php', Webhook.request.getEndpoint());

        if (Webhook.request != null) {
            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(Webhook.request.getBody());
            System.assertNotEquals(null, jsonResponse.get('userId'));
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that im not able to read the JSON data. This is my script that is listening for the data from salesforce

```
<?php
    require_once './salesforceAuth.php';
    // $headers = getallheaders();

    $salesForce = new SalesForce();
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $dataFile = fopen("datasf.txt", "w");

    try {
            var_dump($data);
            
            fwrite($dataFile,$data);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo "Error / " . $th->getMessage();
        } 
?>
```

But I keep getting `string(0) ""`.
Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You pasted apex unit test, not the trigger/class with @future or similar that makes the actual callout? Your callout code probably does not have request.setBody() but it's hard to say without seeing it

Comment: Hey @eyescream yep so im fresh to apex and i really thought thought that I sent the actual code. So this "webhook" was rendered using this app `https://salesforce-webhook-creator.herokuapp.com/app` and the response is shown on this server `https://echo-webhook.herokuapp.com/`

So i basically did a call to the server that is showing the data and im able to manipulate it not. thanks much for you into. 

Cheer!

Answer (score 0):

Capture some logs when creating contacts (open Developer Console from upper right corner, cog/gear icon or look into Setup -> Debug logs). When I tried that code generated by heroku app and endpoint generated with https://requestbin.net/ I could see

```
CALLOUT_REQUEST|[45]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://ok89nqo55upgs7r6.b.requestbin.net, Method=POST]
CALLOUT_REQUEST|[45]|System.HttpRequest retrying request in response to handshake failure: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name
EXCEPTION_THROWN|[45]|System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name
HEAP_ALLOCATE|[45]|Bytes:43
FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name

Class.Webhook.callout: line 45, column 1
```

It seems to be some HTTPS / SSL problem. There's not much info on the net about it, you might be unlucky with the SF instance you're using (sandbox?) or maybe the certificate you used on the php app is suspicious (self signed maybe?)

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093nlIAA
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33275/error-system-calloutexception-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac
- https://blog.bergin.io/system-calloutexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-7d370be2d49b

It's stupid but try to change the Contact trigger to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. And change the Setup -> Remote Site Setting to "disable protocol security". And try again. If it works - you'll know it's something with SSL and you'll have something you can take to SF support.

[image: remote site setting with HTTP instead of HTTPS]

```
trigger ContactHookWebhookTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    String url = 'http://ok89nqo55upgs7r6.b.requestbin.net';
    String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
    Webhook.callout(url, content);
}
```

After I made these changes and created new contact - that request bin captured some payload properly

https://requestbin.net/bins/view/2a2ca78656191cf942600bce8cac9b346006da0b

```
{"new": [{"attributes":{"type":"Contact","url":"/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Contact/0034J00000tNAWtQAO"},"LastModifiedDate":"2022-05-23T08:42:14.000+0000","IsDeleted":false,"IsEmailBounced":false,"DoNotCall":false,"HasOptedOutOfEmail":false,"HasOptedOutOfFax":false,"SystemModstamp":"2022-05-23T08:42:14.000+0000","CleanStatus":"Pending","OwnerId":"0054J000001ipw6QAA","CreatedById":"0054J000001ipw6QAA","CreatedDate":"2022-05-23T08:42:14.000+0000","Id":"0034J00000tNAWtQAO","LastName":"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj","LastModifiedById":"0054J000001ipw6QAA"}], "old": [], "userId": "0054J000001ipw6QAA"}
```

Of course HTTP is evil for potentially sensitive data. If you don't see anything wrong with php app's certificate - I really think raising ticket with sf support would be the way to go.